How can i setup a proxy to redirect traffic to VPN
For work i need 2 use 2 differents VPN to access 2 differents networks.
Switching beetween VPN each time I need to one or the other context is very painfull because of double factor auth etc...
I can run the 2 VPNs simulteanously but it doesn't properly route all applications
Since most of my usage is to access web application in thoses private network I would like to setup 2 proxy each redirect traffic througt one or the other of the VPN so I can setup those proxy on a hostname base or one in each browser:
browser1 -> proxy1 -> vpn1 -> private network 1
browser2 -> proxy2 -> vpn2 -> private network 2

This setup will also allow me to not route my internet traffic through thoses VPNs.
I have already found that I will need to delete the routes and DNS setup that the 2 VPNs are adding but I have identified those configuration and I known the interface I need to route the traffic to.
But I can't find information about which proxy allow to setup such a thing...
Does anybody have already setup such a thing ? Is it possible ?
Thanks
